# How to (and how not to) load a css file that uses @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm trying to load some personal fonts (@font-face) from a css file.

If I use:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

the fonts don't load.

However, using:

```
<style>@import url('css/style.css');</style>
```

they load!

Shouldn't the first method work as well? That's the one I've always used... it's my first time using @font-face though.

Note that with the 1st method the CSS is being applied just fine. It's just the font's that don't load...

Edit:

My CSS starts like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'MyFont-Bold';
    src: url('../type/MyFont-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../type/MyFont-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../type/MyFont-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../type/MyFont-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../type/MyFont-Bold.svg#MyFont-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    unicode-range: U+0020-2212;
}
```

Comment: create font.css and in style.css @import(font.css)

Comment: or use google font throw direct link (google fonts - google it)

Comment: Google fonts is a no go. I'm using a custom font. But I like your first idea. I'm gonna give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: That said, is there a reason why fonts loaded with @font-face don't render using <link href=... ? I'm still curious on why that's not working...

Comment: Show your css, no idea how you implemented it. Fonts work fine for me (and probably everybody else) when using `<link>`.

Comment: @IkoTikashi there's nothing special about it. `<link  href=...` is just like I posted it above and the css is working fine aside from the custom fonts not rendering... I'm using paulirish's bulletproof syntax. and the funny thing is that if I use `<style>@import url(...` to load the css the fonts render fine.

Comment: It's a path thingy I guess, if you `@import` paths are relative to your root, if you `link`, paths will be relative to `/css/`

Comment: Just use correct URLs in your font-face `src` and it will work both ways. When you `<link>` than all URLs inside css are relative to css file itself. If you `import`, than URLs inside are relative to html file. Best way is to start with root as: `/styles/fonts/myfont.ttf`, which means `styles` folder is on root.

Comment: okay, that makes some sense... any downside to sticking with `@import` instead of `link`?

Comment: [Dont use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) explains all.

Comment: @skobaljic thx for the info, but it looks like: a) if I'm only loading one stylesheet using `@import` it shouldn't cause any problems... b) that article is from 2009, I'm not sure how accurate it stands...

Comment: Mate, use valid URLs in your css, don't bother importing. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create font.css and in style.css `@import(font.css)`

read this for ur second question: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/advanced/atrules/

Comment: Actually that way the fonts will be the last thing to load, right? That's not good...

Comment: u can import (font.css) at head of ur .css file*

Comment: Right, but won't that make font.css be the last thing to load?

Comment: no, u can try just change ur path in @font-face src to absolute pathes